# Блокировка/разблокировка кнопки по состоянию строки из DataGridView

Tags: c#

Привет всем. Такая проблема:

Есть DataGridView. В нем отображается информация таблицы из БД. Есть также две кнопки Add и Remove, из названия понятно что они делают.

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы я запрещал пользователю использовать кнопку Remove на те строки, которые были ранее занесены в таблицу, до открытия программы. Кнопка Remove должна быть доступна только для тех строк, которые добавлены во время выполнения программы; как только я закрыл и открыл ее заново, кнопка Remove для тех строк стала недоступна.

В принципе задача элементарная, но хотелось бы сделать ее более продвинуто Как положено так сказать. 
На данное время имею таблицу, в каждой строке таблице есть поле root, которое и дает право кнопки Remove быть разблокированной или заблокированной. Но хотелось бы, конечно, от этого поля избавиться, и сделать по нормальному

Были также мысли проверять состояние строки DataRow, и если оно DataRowState.Added, то тогда разблокируем кнопку, иначе нет...но че-то у меня не вышло с этим...

Кто нибудь знает?

Comment: Вы просите улучшить, но у Вас не представлено Ваше решение, которое нужно сделать лучше. Поэтому, зайдя к Вам на огонек, просвещенная публика удивленно пожимает плечами и бредет дальше по своим делам. Имхо, держать в базе признак и по нему принимать решение о доступе к кнопкам - это нормальное решение. В чем проблема?

Comment: ИМХО,  DataRowState лучше не трогать, оно служит для другого

Comment: Если я буду держать в базе признак доступа к строке - это нормально? Чтож Вы сразу не сказали! Я до этого так и сделал, и все работало:) Спасибо, тогда так и оставлю